# Coding in Controller and Model in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cakephp

I am new in `codeigniter` and I am little bit confused about code written in `Controllers` and `Models` in `Codeigniter`

Best way to write code for `logout`

**Controller** `Logout.php`

```
<?php 
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Logout extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('logout_model');
        }

        function index()
        {
            $this->logout_model->logout();
        }
    }
?>
```

**Model** `Logout_model.php`

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Logout_model extends CI_Model {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        function logout()
        {
            $this->session->userdata = array();
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect(base_url().'admin/login','refresh');
        }
    }
?>
```

Also all our logic not related to `database` should be written in `Model` or `Controller`
Is it correct, that only the `redirections` are handled by `Controllers`?

Same thing if I will do in `Cake php` then what are the changes in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP, Codeigniter and many similar frameworks **do not do MVC correctly**.

The "model" is *"your app"*. Everything your app does belongs in the model. This includes sessions, log in, log out, authentication etc.
The view contains code exclusively related to *presenting and visualizing* data from the model.
The controller is a little bit of glue that holds both parts together, in a web application it mostly deals with receiving input and invoking the correct model method and view.

In short: **The view is interchangeable depending on what output you need, the controller is interchangeable depending on what input you get, the model is not interchangeable because it is your core app.** Once you understand that, a proper MVC structure should be obvious.

Cake and CI put *waaaaaay* too much logic into the controller and keep the models *waaaaay* too thin, to the extend that it's impossible to make a proper MVC app with their default controllers and models. And by "thin models" I mean that they typically only have one type of "model", which is a DAL class. The "model" in MVC is not just one type of class, it is a group of things in whatever shape necessary to *model* your business logic.

So, whatever you do, know that it's not proper MVC. Be aware of the ideal separation described above and that you're never going to attain it using these frameworks.

Comment: "Cake and CI put waaaaaay to much logic into the controller" could you provide an example please?

Comment: @deceze It means, what I code in my `question` is `correct`? Also can you tell me how to use `database` in `helpers`?

Comment: @High Perfect example: the CakePHP EmailComponent is a controller component. Email does not belong in the controller! You send email as part of certain business logic steps; from the model! Further, models are often just DALs with the insert and fetch logic being pushed into the controller. I have little experience with CI, I just know it's similar enough to Cake to also not get it right.

Comment: @Rohan It's weird to have a "logout model". You should have one class in your model whose responsibility is *authentication*. Login and logout are part of that class.

Comment: @High See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html. There's a ton of *business logic* in the controller. Just imagine you want to create an *alternative interface* for your app, say a CLI interface or a RESTful API. For that you probably need a different controller (and view), and you have to duplicate all that code, which should be in a `Post::create()` model action.

Comment: @deceze Means that I can create a `authenticate Model` and I write a function name `logout` there? No matters, whether it is using `database` or `not`? But Ahmed says `So there is no need to write the logic in models that is not related to database.`

Comment: @Rohan Probably. You *should* keep this in a model, but I can't tell you how well this philosophy actually plays together with CI's architecture.

Comment: @RohanKumar MVC in CI is pretty clear to understand http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html. The model is what you do with data (including interact with the database but not only), this is where you place your business logic. Use the controller to analyze requests and decide what model and views to call.

Comment: @deceze For the ton of BL in the controller this looks more like configuration and it's up to you to place it in a model if you think this is a better place. This controller is getting data from a form so yes, it would be better to have another controller or function in this controller to accept it to be called from CLI. I really think this is the developer role to avoid that duplicate code and it is possible to do it with CI, you just need to organize your code the best way necessary to your needs. Some of the examples are 'shortcuts' to understand CI MVC's architecture.

Comment: @High CI may be closer to true MVC than Cake, yes. But the models are still largely DALs and this structure is promoted a lot. It's probably a sufficiently simple form of MVC for simple apps, but is too shallow for complex apps. I'll freely admit that the largest part of my answer is against Cake, which gets it wrong on many levels and is virtually impossible to improve. Maybe CI is somewhat better.

Comment: @deceze and I have never used Cake so I have no opinion on that one. I really like CI and (believe me) the code I write in my models is far but limited to DALs. It's really up to what you want to do and as any other tool you are always free to use it in a bad or a good way :-)

Comment: @deceze EmailComonent was removed long ago, like 2 years ago, Sessions are part of [models (/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php)](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php). And I think you will find it is users that put code in controllers, not Cake.

Comment: @dogmatic69 OK, I'll admit to having given up on Cake a while ago and not having touched 2.0, though I still have to maintain a few 1.x projects. I know you guys are doing good work on it and it's a decent enough framework for certain use cases, but for me the "MVC" label just barely applies. The Controller should not redirect (the View should). The Controller should not formulate complex find conditions, that should be a specific model method. That's really up to the user, but Cake really promotes this practice. A lot of things are very tightly baked together that shouldn't be. (cont'd)

Comment: Does the Controller still carry most of the pagination logic? The ACL logic? And looking at the manual, Email still is a controller component...? Sorry, just my opinion. :)

Comment: The email component is a wrapper (for BC) only. I use custom find methods like Model->find('myAwesomeStuff', $userId) which means there is virtually no code in controllers at all. Its not Cakes fault that most people don't care and put 5k + lines of code in a controller. Pagination is rebuilt as a component that converts the params to a find and passes them to the model. The model should not know about url params as that is business logic.

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter, models are used to interact with the database.
Personally, I would go for a more pragmatic approach and leave out the logout model in your case :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Logout extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('admin/login','refresh');
    }

}

// Omit PHP closing tag to avoid outputting unwanted data
```

[CodeIgniter Style guide : PHP closing tag](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html#php_closing_tag)

Answer (score 0):

Code Igniter follows MVC pattern. That means Model are database layer, Views are front end and Controllers are intermediary layer between models and views. The basic flow of CI is like this.

1. User makes a request (controller's action called)
2. Controller looks if there is some thing to do with the database layer (and performs the functionality)
3. Controller then also sends back the data to the view with required data.

While using CI, we have to follow the MVC rules as we should not `echo` any thing in controllers and models. So there is no need to write the logic in models that is not related to database.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [CodeIgniter document](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html) :

> - The Model represents your data structures. Typically your model classes will contain functions that help you retrieve, insert, and
>     update information in your database.
> - The View is the information that is being presented to a user. A View will normally be a web page, but in CodeIgniter, a view can also
>     be a page fragment like a header or footer. It can also be an RSS
>     page, or any other type of "page".
> - The Controller serves as an intermediary between the Model, the View, and any other resources needed to process the HTTP request and
>     generate a web page.

So I agree with @deceze that: CakePHP, Codeigniter and many similar frameworks do not do MVC correctly.

So if you're familiar with some java framework like hibernate or jpa, you can easier make model of CodeIgniter's model work as ORM system by using a third library like [CI datamapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/) .. It make you model work as a base or database object system where you just care about the nature db object that your system is working with.

Comment: I have troubles to create to controllers and load in the same time, business layer is difficult to implement in MVC inside of CI. I means I have a controller to manage login and I have a controller to manage some logs in system, when some user make login need to set it on log and when try to read or charge the controller I get a error. because I cant load 2 controllers its is the real question

Answer (score 0):

After searching, I got some useful URLs for this,

1. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html
2. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.developer.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fcsdmvcdespat.htm
3. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html
4. http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model

**Model -** This is the part of your application that defines its basic functionality behind a set of abstractions. Data access routines and some business logic can be defined in the model.

**View -** Views define exactly what is presented to the user. Usually controllers pass data to each view to render in some format. Views will often collect data from the user, as well. This is where you're likely to find HTML markup in your MVC applications.

**Controller -** Controllers bind the whole pattern together. They manipulate models, decide which view to display based on the user's request and other factors, pass along the data that each view will need, or hand off control to another controller entirely. Most MVC experts recommend » keeping controllers as skinny as possible.